# How to fix function has already been spied on error in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery, jasmine2.0

I have 3 tests, each testing various methods.

```
it('test function1', function() {
   spyOn(document, 'getElementById');
   // ... some code to test function1
   expect(document.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalled();

 });

it('test function2', function() {
   spyOn(document, 'getElementById');
   // ... some code to test function2
   expect(document.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalled();

 });

it('test function3', function() {
   spyOn(document, 'getElementById');
   // ... some code to test function3
   expect(document.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalled();    
 });
```

But when I run these tests I get the following error: `getElementById has already been spied upon`. Can someone explain why am I getting this error even when spies are in different test suites and how to fix it.

Comment: Why are you spying on and testing native JS/browser code?  I think it's safe to expect that these functions will work when they are called.

Comment: Because test does not load the HTML file, so `document.getElementById('').style` etc in js file will throw error.

Comment: You should probably instead test for the existence of a certain element rather than testing that native browser code was called or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you spy on a method once, you cannot spy on it again. If all you want to do is check to see if it's been called in each test, just create the spy at the beginning of the test, and reset the calls in `afterEach`:

```
     spyOn(document, 'getElementById');

     afterEach(() => {
       document.getElementById.calls.reset();
     });

     it('test function1', function() {
       // ... some code to test function1
       expect(document.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalled();

     });

    it('test function2', function() {
       // ... some code to test function2
       expect(document.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalled();

     });

    it('test function3', function() {
       // ... some code to test function3
       expect(document.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalled();    
     });
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you can spy on a method of a _single object_ only once.

Answer (score 10):

Its late to reply but, if someone is trying to spyon same function multiple times but with different return value you could use

```
it('test function', function() {
   // spy and return data
   spyOn(serviceName,'functionName').and.returnValue(data);
   expect(serviceName.functionName).toHaveBeenCalled();
   
   // spy and return newData
   serviceName.functionName = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(newData);
   expect(serviceName.functionName).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```